# Recognition of data type in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

This is confusing but working code. I just want some help in understanding why k::ks is taken as a'list list list and not a'list list.
I want to take a list and a list of lists and check whether the first list is necessary.
By necessary I mean, whether all of the elements on first list can be found in another.

```
fun do1(a,[],_)=false
|do1(a,k::ks,n)=if a=List.nth(k,n)orelse do1(a,ks,n) then true else false;

val n=0;
fun do2([],k::ks,_)=[]
|do2(_,[],_)=raise unexpected
|do2(l,k::ks,n)=if List.nth(l,n-1)=0 then do2(l,k::ks,n+1)
                        else 
                        if do1(l,k::ks,n) then []
                        else l;
```

Question Repeated:  I just want some help in understanding why k::ks is taken as a'list list list and not a'list list.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the definition of `do2`, `l` is a list. `do2` then calls `do1` with `l` as the first argument, so the first parameter of `do1`, `a`, is also a list. Now on line 2, you do `a = List.nth(k,n)`. So since `a` is a list, `List.nth(k,n)` must also be a list. This means that `k` must be a list of lists. And that in turn means that `k::ks` must be a list of lists of lists.

PS: Generally when trying to find out why the compiler infers a different type than expected, it helps to add type annotations to your function definitions. Often the resulting type errors will give you a much clearer idea of where the compiler's opinion of the types involved starts to differ from yours.

Answer (score 0):

Though this type of codes do not really exchange ideas, I however have included the solution.

In the function,

```
fun do2([],k::ks,_)=[]
|do2(_,[],_)=raise unexpected
|do2(l,k::ks,n)=if List.nth(l,n-1)=0 then do2(l,k::ks,n+1)
                        else 
                        if do1(l,k::ks,n) then []
                        else l;
```

the second last line

```
if do1(l,k::ks,n) then []
```

should be

```
if do1(List.nth(l,n-1),k::ks,n) then []
```